# Facebook Sharer issue (always shows (+) and (%) behind every word))

Tags: facebook, share

I would like to ask how I can fix my Facebook sharer issue. Whenever I want to share my article via Facebook sharer, it pops up the facebook window, which is totaLly ok. But in the window it shows pluses (+) and (%) behind every single word. Can You guys help me with it? You can take a look here at my website: http://www.asiancrib.com/post/test-2/
It will not let me put me screenshot of it.
Tap on facebook share button and it will popup facebook window. There you will see the issue.

Comment: which language you write the share method ? can you paste it?

Answer (score 0):

You might need to add meta in your page

Facebook Load the meta tag to put into it's post

like this

```
<head>
<meta property="og:title" content="This will put in Facebook Post's Title">
<meta property="og:description" content="This will put in Facebook Post's Detail">
....
</head>
```

you can read all meta tag for Facebook Share here

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/best-practices

---

after you update your page

you need to go to this page to let facebook clear cache and reload your website again.

https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object/

Comment: I just put it into the plugin called Add Meta tags.. it is still the same, it shows + and % .. Is there some other way please?

Comment: try check it again, it just the facebook cache still keep the old one.

ALSO, everytime you update your page and want to reload your page immedietely you need to go to this link: https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object/